# Determine if a Network has any sites created already

Tags: multisite

I have a multisite installation and I'm trying to determine if a site has any blogs already created. I can get the current site id by using the following code:

```
$current_site = get_current_site();
$current_site_id = $current_site->id;
echo "The current_site_id is: ".$current_site_id;
```

I need to get the number of blogs created for the site. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing using this code:

```
global $current_site;
$current_site_id = $current_site->id;
$args = array(
    'network_id' => $current_site_id,
);
$site_info = wp_get_sites( $args );
$num_of_sites = sizeof($site_info);
```

If anyone has a more elegant way of solving please post your answer.